# Set pixels of raster NA based on their location

Tags: r, for-loop, na, r-raster

I have a raster which has 50+ bands. What I would like to is to search for all pixel == 0 within the first band of the raster. Following I would like to set all of these pixels NA in the other raster bands as well. Thus, I don't have to do the search for 0 again 50+ times. Here is my example:

```
cl_input <- brick("sometif")
for(i in 1:nlayers(cl_input)){
    print(names(cl_input[[i]]))
    cl_input[[i]][cl_input[[i]] == 0] <- NA   
}
```

I hope I stated out my need clearly =)

Thanks in advance,
cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `mask` method; using the first layer as the mask, and by setting the maskvalue to zero.

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(nrow=2, ncol=2, nl=3)
values(b) <- matrix(c(0,1,1),4,3)
values(b)
##     layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
##[1,]       0       1       1
##[2,]       1       1       0
##[3,]       1       0       1
##[4,]       0       1       1

d <- mask(b, b[[1]],  maskvalue=0)
values(d)
##     layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
##[1,]      NA      NA      NA
##[2,]       1       1       0
##[3,]       1       0       1
##[4,]      NA      NA      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop here. You can search for 0 in all layers at once:

```
cl_input <- brick("sometif")
cl_input[cl_input == 0] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the I am still searching through every single band, right?

Comment: Technically yes. If you want to search only the first layer do `cl_input[[1]][cl_input[[1]] == 0] <- NA`. But if you want to change the value for 0-pixels to NA in all layers, the method above is the fastest

Comment: Thanks smoff, then I will apply your method as suggested. I just thought there might be a way to use the location. Anyhow, thanks!

Comment: Well I tested it and received this error: 

'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL

I can't imaging where this problem comes from.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the actual `brick`. Could you include a reproducible example in your question?